# Google Glass: Is there anyway to cleanup the timeline

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

Google Glass makes it very easy for Glassware apps to 'liter' the timeline (especially with news items). Is there any easy way to clean/delete items you don't want?

Many of these items cannot be deleted, and the apps themselves (like Winkfeed for example) don't seem to have that feature. I know your OWN apps can delete their own items, but haven't found a way to delete/manage ALL the items on my timeline (including those created by other apps).

Comment: have you tried to remove apps from your my glass account? https://glass.google.com/glassware

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**If you're developing a Glassware**

You can use the Mirror API's [delete](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/delete) method or tools like [Glass Cleaner](http://cremeglass.com/glass-cleaner/) to clear up timeline items.

**If you're a user of a Glassware**

The management of the timeline items is up to the developer of the Glassware. There's no way to override this from Glass, but your timeline isn't infinite. They'll fall off the timeline after about 7 days, or when your timeline exceeds about 200 items.

In general, the design philosophy for Glass is to discourage you from managing your timeline like an email inbox. By design it discourages you from achieving timeline zero.  The intent is to avoid using it like a fire hose that you try to manage, but instead to think of it like a stream that you dip your toe into now and then.

Comment: I hope you guys are learning from the frequency of this feedback.  See Win8 for what happens when you ignore feedback in the name of a new design principle.  People should at the very least have a way to "uninstall" a glassware (removing all its cards) and a way of quickly viewing just new/unread notifications...  While I appreciate the design principles, the clutter created by old/stale cards is unpleasant... and it *is* clutter because my goal while scrolling through the timeline is to see what notifications I missed but scrolling too fast lands me on stuff I saw 5 days ago.

Comment: Agreed..not sure if its just bad UI design or the desire to be 'spammy' but some Glassware tend (especially the news ones) to LITTER the timeline - horrible implications for these spammy apps (could potentially send 100's of items with no way for you to remove them)

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, but this may not be the best place. For stuff like that, please ping the Glass Guides. I hate to redirect you, but feedback here is tantamount to cat > /dev/null :)

Answer (score 0):

How to delete your Google Glass timeline:
hook your Glass up to a Windows computer, get adb open a dos shell to run adb

```
start adb 
type adb devices
type adb root
type adb shell
type cd /data/data/com.google.glass.sync/databases
type rm timeline.db
type rm timeline.db-shm
type rm timeline.db-wal
```

reboot your Google Glass and it will recreate an empty timeline database